# "The digits used in artificial numbers are random while the real numbers aren't and their digits distribution is specific to their business"

Tags: statistics, math-history, algorithmic-randomness

Related to the question https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1924178/tools-to-measure-the-nonrandomness-of-database, I'm somehow looking for some tools to measure the nonrandomness of databases. Igael gave me a hint I don't understand so far : "the digits used in artificial numbers are random while the real numbers aren't and their digits distribution is specific to their business".

**Question :** Could anyone be able to explain to me in details what it means exactly?

Comment: This is a very broad question, perhaps you could narrow it down a bit?  In practice, people often prefer to use [Pseudo Random Numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudorandom_number_generator) as they are easy to generate rapidly and you can reproduce them to check past work.  Some standard tests of randomness are described [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Randomness_tests)

Comment: To your specific question:  it is not possible to write down a truly random real number, just for counting reasons.  Probabilistically, almost all real numbers are uncomputable...meaning no computer program of finite length will output its digits.  Not sure if your source means anything more precise than this...as I say, your question is very broad.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps you might be interested in [Benford's law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Benford%27s_law):

> Benford's law, also called the first-digit law, is an observation about the frequency distribution of leading digits in many real-life sets of numerical data. The law states that in many naturally occurring collections of numbers, the leading significant digit is likely to be small. For example, in sets which obey the law, the number 1 appears as the most significant digit about 30% of the time, while 9 appears as the most significant digit less than 5% of the time. By contrast, if the digits were distributed uniformly, they would each occur about 11.1% of the time. Benford's law also makes (different) predictions about the distribution of second digits, third digits, digit combinations, and so on.

Comment: Myyy gooood, thanks!